# SAS Macro Works Standalone, But Not When Looped

Tags: sas

I have a large dataset where I am storing macro parameters. The macro is itself used to call a number of other macros, each of which runs a number of operations.

Ideally, I'd like to use another macro to loop over each row of the dataset, construct (using `PROC SQL`)  a macro call, store it in a macro variable `:CALL`, and call the variable at every iteration of the loop (with a `PUT &CALL.;`) That is:

```
 %macro OUTER_LOOP(DS);
    %let K = ;
    %COUNT_ROWS(DS, K); /* This stores the number of rows in DS in K. */
    %do i = 1 %to &K.;
        proc sql noprint; ...; quit; /* Create the macro call, and store it in :CALL. */
        %put &CALL.;
    %end;
    %mend;
    %OUTER_LOOP;
```

This doesn't work as expected: some of the internal checks that exist in my macro indicate several datasets created by the macro are missing. Curiously, when I *don't* run this in a macro loop (i.e. I manually create a macro call, row-by-row, and execute it), no error occurs.

Has anyone experienced this issue? If so, is anyone familiar with a solution that would still allow me to loop over macro calls? I know that `CALL EXECUTE();` (in the data step) runs different parts of the macro at different times--is that what is occurring in this case, as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would add `%put Loop iterating: i=&i k=&k ;`  inside the DO loop.  That will let you see how many times the loop iterates.  One possibility is the loop is exiting earlier than you intend it to.  If that is the case, the cause could be a collision between the macro variable `i` you use for the looping in %Outer_Loop and another macro variable `i` you use in one of the inner macros you call.  As a general rule, it's a good idea to define macro variables as `%LOCAL` to the macro they are defined in.  Doing that will prevent such macro variable collisions.  But without seeing the inner macros, that's just one possibility.

You could also add `%put %superq(Call) ;` inside the do loop.  That will show you the macro calls that are being generated, so you can check you are getting the expected parameter values in each call.

Comment: Unfortunately, the iteration breaks on the very first loop. Your point on ensuring `i` isn't inside any of the inner loops is well-taken, but it doesn't appear to be at the source of the issue: even when I change the outermost loop variable name to something unique, the macro still stops execution. 

The core problem appears to be in a macro-within-the-macro. Specifically, there is one macro that generates a dataset, followed by another macro that checks whether the first dataset exists and aborts if it does not. The dataset is *always* created, but the check fails within the macro.

Comment: Then suggest you edit your question to show the code that is checking the existence of the dataset and aborting.  Or if you are sure the dataset is not being created, then maybe should show that part.  Better yet, maybe copy your code to a new program, and cut it down until you have a reasonably sized complete example that illustrates the problem, and post that.

Comment: In relation to Quentin's suggestion, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a scoping issue.  Your sub-macros are likely overwriting the values of your macro variables in your calling-macros.

You can fix this by declaring all your variables as local variables using the `%local` statement.  If there are macro variables that you need to access after the macros have run, explicitly declare them as `%global`.

So for the macro you have listed above you will need the below line:

```
%local k i;
```

Don't forget you need to do this for any sub-macros that are called, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a lot of these types of problems by generating the code yourself. For your example you could move the logic that generates the code from SQL to a data step and then instead of a macro you just need a data step.  You don't even need know the number of observations in the dataset in advance.

```
filename code temp ;
data _null_;
    set DS ;
    file code ;
    put '.... generated code based on values in current data ... ;
run;
%include code / source2 ;
```